How to get rid of "Unexpected end of JSON input" error at PayPal Payouts fetch request
Im tyring to make a request to Paypal's Payouts api, but when i do and i try to get the response from "payoutResponse.json()" i get the following error:
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at C:\Users\Administrator\coin_money_maker\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:273:32
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Query.onResult (C:\Users\Administrator\coin_money_maker\index.js:1368:36) {
  type: 'invalid-json'
}

and so when i try to log the response before the .json() at the end i get this
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts',
    status: 500,
    statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}

I got no idea what to do, thanks in advance.

Deal with the 500 error instead, maybe get the response as text() instead of json() because PayPal does not respond with json in case of server errors.

I tried to log payoutResponse.text(), but it didn't log anything, just a new line...

Try using postman to actually inspect the payload you are receiving. It might have more information about the error?

Then the body is empty, that is a very possible situation. Nothing to suggest the opposite. As I said you need to investigate why you get a 500, start debugging. As mentioned maybe use postman but if you simply get no response data you will not gain any insights that way either.
